# Need Pyspark String to Date Conversion Pattern

Tags: apache-spark, date, pyspark, type-conversion

I have a string field with datetime in this format:

```
Thu Jul 01 09:26:47 UTC 2021
```

I have gone through spark documentation for date_format function and tried this one:

```
E L dd hh:mm:ss UTC yyyy
```

Still I get NULL and cant parse the string into datetime. any help would be appreciated.

```py
df.select('Created Time', F.to_timestamp(F.col('Created Time'), 'E L dd hh:mm:ss UTC yyyy'))
  .show(1, False)
```

Comment: are you **converting** from string to timestamp with `to_timestamp`, or are you **formatting** a date with `date_format`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [escape](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) `UTC` and consider it as "text", not part of the date pattern.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp

df = spark.createDataFrame(["Thu Jul 01 09:26:47 UTC 2021"], "string").toDF("TS_String")

df\
  .withColumn("TS_Converted", unix_timestamp(df.TS_String, "E MMM d h:m:s 'UTC' yyyy")\
  .cast("timestamp"))\
  .show()
```